# Android and Guice - How to pass a parameter?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, guice, code-injection, roboguice

I want to be able to inject an object, and pass a parameter to its initializer method.
Is this possible?

```
public class MyObject
{
  @Inject
  public MyObject(int anInteger)
  {
    //do something
  }
}


public class MyActivity extends RoboActivity
{
   @Inject (anInteger = 5) MyObject myObject;
   // I want to be able to pass an object to be used when calling the 
   // initializer method
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do it with `bindConstant()` and annotating it accordingly.  See, for example, [How do I inject configuration parameters?](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyModule extends AbstractModule
{
  @Override
  protected void configure()
  {
    bind(Integer.class).
        annotatedWith(Names.named("my.object.an.integer")).
        toInstance(500);
  }

  @Provides
  @Named("an.integer.5")
  public MyObject myObject5()
  {
    return createMyObject(5);
  }

  @Provides
  @Named("an.integer.100")
  public MyObject providesMyObject100()
  {
    return createMyObject(100);
  }

  private MyObject createMyObject(int anInteger)
  {
    MyObject result = new MyObject(anInteger);
    // if there are any other fields/setters annotated with @Inject
    requestInjection(result);
    return result;
  }
}


public class MyObject
{
  public MyObject(int anInteger)
  {
    System.out.println("anInteger = " + anInteger);
  }
}

public class User
{
  @Inject
  @Named("an.integer.5")
  private field MyObject five;

  @Inject
  @Named("an.integer.100")
  private field MyObject hundred;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. but that's not what I meant. I want to specify the variable in my activity when Injecting the object. for example: @Inject (anInteger = 5) MyObject myObject;, and when this get's called it passed 5 to the instructor method, this way I can pass different objects in different activities

Comment: Then you should use @Provides methods